# Wordclouds with absolute word sizes

Tags: r, word-cloud

I'm trying to make several wordclouds to compare terms, which themselves are nested within groups. I would like to make one wordcloud per group. The `wordcloud` package in R can make the wordclouds I need, but each new wordcloud has the size of the words scaled *relatively* to the maximum and minimum word frequency. This is able to be set with the `scale` parameter.

My aim is to make wordclouds where the size of the word is absolutely related to the frequency of the word, enabling different wordclouds to be visually compared.

```
library(wordcloud)
dat <- data.frame(word = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2), freq =  c(10, 5, 3, 20, 10, 6), group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))

dat
#  word freq group
#1    A   10     1
#2    B    5     1
#3    C    3     1
#4    A   20     2
#5    B   10     2
#6    C    6     2

wordcloud(dat$word[dat$group == 1], dat$freq[dat$group == 1]) 
wordcloud(dat$word[dat$group == 2], dat$freq[dat$group == 2]) # Currently the same
```

[image: Current wordcloud]

This is the current wordcloud I get from the above command, run on both groups in the MWE (although the exact placement will vary randomly with each run). I would like each letter in the second group's wordcloud to be twice as large as the first, in line with the data (or for there to be some sensible scaled difference, even if it is not linear).

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way of doing this in wordcloud. I'd be interested to see  if anyone can find one! You could try making the wordclouds in ggplot: http://mhairihmcneill.com/blog/2016/04/05/wordclouds-in-ggplot.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, this might be a roundabout way. But what if we set the scale for all data using a single anchor.

```
anchor <- max(dat$freq)
wordcloud(dat$word[dat$group == 1], dat$freq[dat$group == 1], scale = c(8*max(dat$freq[dat$group == 1])/anchor, 0.5))
wordcloud(dat$word[dat$group == 2], dat$freq[dat$group == 2], scale = c(8*max(dat$freq[dat$group == 2])/anchor, 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice workaround that, even if it doesn't make two wordclouds exactly proportional, is good enough for comparison. I think that anything beyond this is probably not possible using `wordcloud` — yet I struggle to find well developed and technically capable software packages that can make wordclouds and similar designs. If anyone has suggestions, that would be great.